# How to not use gradle in IntelliJ to execute Kotlin main

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I created a simple Kotlin project with the Console template in IntelliJ and running it I am getting the gradle-symbol in the run-toolwindow (cf. picture).

[image]

Usually I see in other tutorials that there is the Kotlin symbol so no gradle is used to run the main of the Kotlin-project.

Is there any possibility to change the way to run a Kotlin-main (despite the run configurations, which I took a look at, but did not find a way to change the "run-environment")

I tried the solution:

CTRL + ALT + S to enter `Settings` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Build Tools` > `Gradle`, switching `Build and run using` to `IntelliJ IDEA`, then getting the problem:

[image]

Which is closer, but now it seems to get a problem as in Java, what I thought in Kotlin is no problem to have different file names then the actual code-content of the file.

Answer (score 2):

As described in [**Configure the build and run actions**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-projects.html#delegate_build_gradle) topic use Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Build and run using:** option and switch it to *IntelliJ IDEA*:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

CTRL + ALT + S to enter `Settings` then in the left panel choose `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Build Tools` > `Gradle`, find `Build and run using` and pick `IntelliJ IDEA`